# C. Check input of a float for a certain number of decimal places

Tags: c, error-checking

Good morning. The code I have written is made to calculate the amount of change given in a transaction, the change portion only, the paper change is ignored. I would like to do an error check to make sure that the user entered # does not exceed 2 decimal places. This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void intro();
void instructions();
void getvalues(float *owe, float *paid);
float totalchange(float *owe, float *paid);
void quarters (float *change);
void dimes (float *change);
void nickels (float *change);
void pennies (float *change);

int main()
{
    float owe = 0.0, paid = 0.0, change;
    int a = 2;
    intro();
    instructions();

        printf("Would you like to continue?\n1: Continue\n0: Exit\n");
        scanf("%i", &a);
        if (a== 0)
            exit(0);

        while (a == 1){
            getvalues(&owe, &paid);
            while (owe > paid)
                getvalues(&owe, &paid);
            change = totalchange(&owe, &paid);
            quarters (&change);
            dimes (&change);
            nickels (&change);
            pennies (&change);

            printf("Would you like to make another calculation?\n1: Continue\n0: Exit\n");
            scanf("%i", &a);
    }

    return 0;
}

void intro(){
    printf("Program: Homework 1 Part 1 :: Change Calculator\nAuthor: Jason Golightly\nDate:5-13-15\nVersion 1.0\n\n");
}


void instructions(){
    printf("This program is designed to calculate the coin\nportion of the change given after a purchase.\n");
    printf("When prompted, please enter the purchase amount and the amount paid.\nThe amount paid must exceed the purchase amount.\n");
}

void getvalues(float *owe, float *paid){

        printf("Please enter the amounts in a dollars.cents fashion\n\nPurchase amount?\n");
        scanf("%f", owe);
        printf("\nAmount paid?\n");
        scanf("%f", paid);
        printf("\n");
        if (*owe > *paid)
            printf("ERROR. Please enter valid amounts.\n");
        if (*owe == *paid)
            printf("You have given exact change.\n")

}

float totalchange(float *owe, float *paid){
    int a;
    a = (*paid - *owe)*100;
    a = a % 100;
    printf("total change = %i\n",a);
    return a;
}
void quarters (float *change){
    int q;
    q = *change / 25;
    printf("Quarters = %i\n", q);
    *change = *change - 25*q;
}
void dimes (float *change){
    int d;
    d = *change / 10;
    printf("Dimes = %i\n", d);
    *change = *change - 10*d;
}

void nickels (float *change){
    int n;
    n = *change / 5;
    printf("Nickels = %i\n", n);
    *change = *change - 5*n;
}
void pennies (float *change){
    int p;
    p = *change / 1;
    printf("Pennies = %i\n\n", p);
    *change = *change - 1*p;
}
```

Also, in case you have not noticed, I am fairly new to programming. If you see anything else I could be doing better, please feel free to point it out.

Thanks, Jason

Comment: Just a couple of words of warning, unrelated to your problem: Using floating point variables for money works for simple school exercises, not in real life due to the inherent rounding problems. Also, due to the rounding you should be careful when comparing for equality or inequality, as two floating point variables that should be equal might actually not be.

Comment: As for your problem, using the standard `scanf` function there's no way you could stop the user from inputting more digits than you want. You probably have to read and parse the input one character at a time yourself.

Comment: @ Joachim. I know what your saying, because I am actually getting wrong values most of the time and its because of that. If I put in $3.45, the value actually becomes 3.4500005 or something along those lines. So how do accomplish this without using a float?

Comment: You have to use [fixed point arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic), which might be outside the scope of your assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On simple approach to avoid the in-exact floating point calculation is to read the input as a string, parse it into a `int`, and display it as *.##

i.e.

```
char number[11];
scanf("%10s", number);
int actual_number = parse(number); // parse the string here.
```

This actual number is basically dollar*100 + cents - which is an `int`.
Now perform all the calculations and display like this:

```
float f = (float)actual_number/100.f ;
printf("%.2f", f);
```

In the `parse` routine, you only consider the first two digits after encountering a `.`

[Here](http://ideone.com/B6MDTH) is an example of the parse routine in C.